# beautifulsoup разное поведение работы при обработке страницы на сайте и на локальном диске

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

пытаюсь парсить:

https://auto.ru/cars/honda/jazz/all/?transmission=AUTO&transmission=AUTOMATIC&transmission=ROBOT&transmission=VARIATOR

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://auto.ru/cars/honda/jazz/all/?transmission=AUTO&transmission=AUTOMATIC&transmission=ROBOT&transmission=VARIATOR'
HEADERS = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
    }

r = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
r.encoding = 'utf-8'

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')
cards = soup.find_all('div', class_='ListingItem-module__container ListingCars-module__listingItem')
print(cards)
```

выдает пустой список. Хотя если сохранить эту же самую страницу и снова прогнать:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
jazz = open('jazz.html', encoding='utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(jazz, 'html5lib')

cards = soup.find_all('div', class_='ListingItem-module__container ListingCars-module__listingItem')
print(cards)
```

то выдает заполненный список для дальнейшего разбора.

В чем причина такого отличия в работе?

Comment: как вы получили данные для файла jazz.html? скопировали исходный код страницы из браузера?

Comment: А вы посмотрите, что у вас в `r.text` получается. Оно там спрашивает согласия на использование куки. В общем, надо разбираться - то ли `Selenium` надо использовать, то ли смотреть на какую ссылку оно само там переходит потом при перезагрузке страницы.

Comment: Jack_os сохранил страницу на комп